# Header issue while accessing Web Service through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, cordova

I am developing a phonegap application which loads data from rest web service.

I load data with ajax request. but for that, I need to set `allow access origin : *` on server end.

But, it works fine in following conditions,

1) While accessing the same WebService through postman/rest client there is no need to change any thing on server end.

2) While accessing the same WebService through IOS/Android native code there is no need to change any thing on server end.

My concern is that is there any work around to access the web service through ajax without changing any thing on server end.

I am unable to use `jsonp` because it uses GET for request.

Comment: Is your response in `json` format?

Comment: are domains of web service and server rendering page containing ajax same?

Comment: @Jai : yes my response is JSON format.

Comment: @Barewithme : no both dooming are different. because in rendering part will happen in phonegap. which is inside mobile application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accessing Cross-Origin Resources `allow access origin` is mandatory for security [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) that should be followed by all the browsers, here is [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

If you think why it is mandatory have a look at this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/why-is-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-necessary)

So from your comment, Ajax to work with your web service you need to implement `allow access origin` and I would suggest to use specific properties to avoid security incidents e.g. `allow access origin: http://yourwebsite.com/websevice`  you will also have to use `JSONP` with this.

[Here is one more reference to CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: thanks for your replay. But still, I have confusion about how postman loads data.

Comment: postman generates individual rest request! on some level you can compare it to as URL that you past on your browser address bar and hit  enter.This does not require to follow security specification, but where as ajax request is generated by browser when it is parsing `JavaScript` which can lead to security risks.